# CSS how to override /deep/

Tags: css, angular, sass, overriding, shadow-dom

```
/deep/ .myColor {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Assume now that 'myColor' appears in the parent component html where myColor is defined in the css, but also in all the child components, grand-child components etc.

If I want to go to grand-child component A, how can I override the /deep/ myColor...

OR is my only choice to remove class="myColor" from the grandchild and replace it with a local class definition like:

```
   .myDifferentColor {
       background-color: green;
    }
```

That works until I want to interrupt the definition of red for the grand-child and all ITS children and grand-children... thus, I have a mess.

My personal choice to avoid "global definitions" as much as possible and thus I don't use /Deep/, but the project I'm on uses it 250 times!

Thanks in advance,
Yogi

Comment: The rule in the grandchild a should automatically override the `/deep/` selector, assuming your using `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` (which is the default). Are you able to create a StackBlitz which reproduces your problem?

Comment: You can try with css "!important" property like: .myDifferentColor {
       background-color: green !important;
    }

Comment: I haven't been able to override the deep definition in any way.  I will build a small test model that we can play with and get back to you here.  Thanks.  Yogi